# GAS - take value from jquery and pass it over to a var in the code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am trying to take the email value from the jquery and pass it over to a var in the code.gs. The code that I currently have is:

code.gs:

```
function getUser(){
  user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return user;
}
 function getUsername(){

  Logger.log(emailSource);
  Console.log(emailSource);
}
```

Jquery:

```
    var user;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getUserEmail).getUser();
function getUserEmail(userMail){
  user = userMail;
  $("#username").ready(function(){
   $("#username").text(userMail);
    });
}
    function getUserEmail2code(emailSource){
   var emailSource = $('#username').text();
   $('#username').append(emailSource);
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getUserEmail2code).getUsername();
    });
```

My Idea is to grab that email address to be able to manipulate with the google sheets and assign specific rules to each.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass values from Client JavaScript to server code you have to use a very similar workflow, below is a shematic example with comments:

*(be careful to check the \' used near the onclick to add the parameters)*

```
  ...
  var someValue = $('#someDIV').val(); // get a value using JQuery and insert it in the onclick
  ...
  $('#someOtherDiv').append('<br><input type="button" id="someID" onclick="someFunctiont(\''+someValue+'\')" value="this will call the function with parameter">');
  ...

  function someFunction(parameter){
    //call a server function here  using Google.script.run
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(otherClientFunctionToEventuallyDoSomething).serverFunction(parameter);
    ...


// in server .gs code :
  function serverFunction(parameter){
    // do something with the parameters...
  }
```

Comment: Hey Serge, I've updated the question with some of the info you said but still cant make it to work. If possible can you take a look?

Comment: Hey again, can you take a look again? Sorry it is just because I can't do it. Thanks.